# How to retrieve data from NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, nsuserdefaults, mpmediaitemcollection

currently, I try make an music playlist application. I try to save and retrieve playlist data from NSUserDefaults. I have no problem when saving the data but I got an error when retrieving data.

I got:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'MPMediaItemCollectionInitException', reason: '-init is not supported, use -initWithItems:

I'm following the answer from [Play iPod playlist retrieved from a saved persistentid list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702707/play-ipod-playlist-retrieved-from-a-saved-persistentid-list) but I try to write it in swift.

here is my save function:

```
func savePlaylist(var mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection){

    var items: NSArray = mediaItemCollection.items

    var listToSave: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for song in items{

        var persistentId: AnyObject! = song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID)

        listToSave.addObject(persistentId)

    }

    var data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(listToSave)

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "songsList")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

}
```

and here is my retrieve function:

```
func setupMusic(){

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("songsList") != nil{

        var theList: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

        var data: NSData = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("songsList") as? NSData)!

        var decodedData: NSArray  = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? NSArray)!

        theList.addObjectsFromArray(decodedData as [AnyObject])

        var allTheSongs: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

        for var i = 0; i < theList.count; i++ {

            var songQuery = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()

            var songs: NSArray = songQuery.items

            allTheSongs.addObject(songs)

        }

        var currentQueue: MPMediaItemCollection = MPMediaItemCollection()

        myMusicPlayer?.setQueueWithItemCollection(currentQueue)


    }else{
        println("fail!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    }

}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the issue `var currentQueue: MPMediaItemCollection = MPMediaItemCollection()`

You must `init` with items

As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItemCollection_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMediaItemCollection/initWithItems:) by apple.

> init(items:)
>   Designated Initializer
>
> Initializes a media item collection with an array of media items.
>   Declaration
>
> Swift
>
> init!(items items: [AnyObject]!)
>   Parameters
>   items
>
> The array of items you are assigning to the media item collection.

You have to init with items like

```
var currentQueue: MPMediaItemCollection = MPMediaItemCollection(items:itemsArray)
```

Comment: where do i put init!(items items: [AnyObject]!)?

Comment: where "itemsArray" come from?

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you a very simple way to any kind of object and retrieve from `NSUserDefault` . 
You don't need to use explicitly archive and unarchive . 
Just create a category of NSUserDefaults as follow

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface NSUserDefaults (AKSNSUserDefaults)
- (void)saveCustomObject:(id<NSCoding>)object
                     key:(NSString *)key;
- (id<NSCoding>)loadCustomObjectWithKey:(NSString *)key;
@end  

@implementation NSUserDefaults (AKSNSUserDefaults)

- (void)saveCustomObject:(id<NSCoding>)object
                     key:(NSString *)key {
    NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object];
    [self setObject:encodedObject forKey:key];
    [self synchronize];

}

- (id)loadCustomObjectWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSData *encodedObject = [self objectForKey:key];
    id object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];
    return object;
}

@end
```

and than your NSUserDefaults is ready to store any object . but one thing is need to use `NSCoder` in your object model .

for example :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AKSClassA : NSObject<NSCoding>
// declared some property 
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger userID;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *userName;
@end
#import "AKSClassA.h"
@implementation AKSClassA
@synthesize userID;
@synthesize userName;
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if (self = [super init]) {

        self. userID = [aDecoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"userID"];
        self. userName = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"userName"];

   }
    return self;
}
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
    [aCoder encodeInteger:userID  forKey:@"userID"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:userName forKey:@"userName"];
}
@end
// in some class if you are using classA object member to store and retrieve with value  example below 
// to save data in NSUserDefaults 
  AKSClassA *obj =[array1 objectAtIndex:index];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] saveCustomObject:button key:@"userData"];

// to retrieve data 
 AKSClassA *obj1 = (AKSClassA*)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]loadCustomObjectWithKey:@"userData"];

    [titleLabel  setText:obj1.userName];
```

Comment: if you are using swift then you can use NSCoding in you model by following this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238868/swift-nscoding-not-working